# CI new default controller not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Have problem with CI 3.0
if i leave default controller in routes.php file "welcome" everything is working perfectly.
BUT if I change it i.e. "main" CI starts to throw 404 error
main controller for first steps is the same as welcome. I just copied files. renamed, changed class name (ofcourse), and in `index()` loading view. 
any suggestions?

also I forgot to tell
on wamp localhost everything is working.. but in server NOT.. :/

And one more thing... 
i.e. if I try go to mydomain.com/welcome - working,
if I try go to mydomain.com/main - NOT.
even if i change routes default controller back to welcome

My main.php file:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {
    function index(){
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

my routes.php file:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['default_controller'] = 'main';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: I think you forgot to change the class name to `Main extends CI_controller`or the file name main.php .write your main controller with the question.

Comment: Can you provide the code for your controller and routes file?

Comment: sadly but I didn't forget to change class name.. :/ 
as I was saying it's strange for me, because in my localhost everything is working.. :/ 
but then I copied all files to server... and it's not working.. unless I put welcome as a default controller in routes.php

Comment: Your controller's file name must start with an uppercase. In your case, Main.php. http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html : «changed filenaming convention (class file names now must be Ucfirst and everything else in lowercase). »

Comment: does mydomain/index.php/main work?

Comment: OMG!! :// thanks!!! :)) 
I was soo use to simple lower cases in file names that I didn't tried that.. :) 
many thanks!! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As said in the comments : Your controller's file name must start with an uppercase. In your case, Main.php. 
See http://codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html

«changed filenaming convention (class file names now must be Ucfirst and everything else in lowercase). »

Answer (score 4):

You just need to set your default controller in `application/config/routes.php` like

```
$route['default_controller'] = $this->set_directory('front/home/').'home/index';
```

for Ci 3.x

Comment: You are a savior. When default controller is inside a folder none of the solution works except yours. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

i stuck with this problem.
i fixed it just replacing the path.
here "site" folder is the default if you want to use CI, you have to store your all code into "site" folder. if you have not used site folder for installation it ll not work with multiple controller setting.
hence you get default controller as a workable and rest of others appeared 404.

change .htacess file in your root directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/index.php/$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /codeig/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

above u can see there is
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /codeig/index.php/$1 [L]`
changed line for "codeig" root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `function index()` to **Public**.
If that doesnt work, then try to add in the URL: domain.com/**index.php/**main
and see what happens. Some times u need .htaccess in the other server to remove the *index.php*.

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter 3 they are adding extra code to force the names of the files to start with an upper case letter. Here's a fix for this one.

In `system/core/Router.php` change the line (about `303`)

```
if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->directory.ucfirst($class).'.php'))
```

to

```
if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$class.'.php'))
```

I had to remove stuff in `CodeIgniter.php` and `Loader.php` as well.