# codeingter3 HMVC 'default_controller' is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, hmvc

I am using CI3 HMVC in my project. Now, I am facing problem with routing. I want user to type www.demosite.com and it would automatically call my home module. I do not want to show like www.demosite.com/home. I want to show the url like www.demo.com.  for this,  I set default controller in application/config/routes, like this, as follows;

`$route['default_controller'] = "home";`

also in my content module, I added a route folder where I wrote

```
$route['home'] = 'home';
```

Here is my .htaccess

```
    AddType text/x-component .htc
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond $1 !(index\.php|assets/)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

This is my home controller

```
class Home extends MX_Controller{
  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

  }

  function index($stub=""){
    $baseUrl=base_url();
    $this->load->helper("url");

      echo $this->_showHomepage();      

  }
}
```

However, when I run this. I got 404 error.  What can i do to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the Home controller?

Comment: ok..i edited my question ..u can see it above

Comment: Hmm, that's the complete controller? And what's the controller's file name?

Comment: file name is home

Comment: Try [upper case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28302274/3890673)

Comment: I tried that...but still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207767/discussion-between-crusy-and-surma).

Answer (score 0):

HMVC it should be like that

This only takes a method no directories are allowed
so the default controller is under controllers

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/pages/view';

$route['default_controller'] = 'pages';
```

index is the default method that is called.

```
$route['home'] = 'authentication/home/index';

$route['home'] = 'authentication/home';
```

And than you need to change your .htaccess file to match that urls

URI Routing : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

**Update :**

```
(defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->view('url');
    }

}
```

Comment: why have u used authentication ...is it a module name

Comment: I edited my question...i have added my .htaccess file. 1 more thing i did not get..why have u used page/page/view

Comment: because route calls your file names

Comment: if i type ...demosite/home...thn its work...but i want to show home controller only in demosite.com

Comment: what do you get when you change `base_url();` to this `site_url();`

Comment: See updated answer please ! check link given in answer for routings

Comment: what would be the default controller .....in default controller i used home/home...but its not working

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I moved the Home folder from Modules folder to Controller folder and then, it just started to work